# Mesa warning: Window 3145746 has no colormap! [OpenFoam]

Tags: paraview

I am new to OpenFoam and running the lid driven flow using paraFoam. The paraFoam command seems to work fine but when I view the velocity and pressure profile, I don't see the colormap variation as expected. Please refer following images -

[P plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB8ze.png)

[U plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmhDn.png)

I am using the openfoam paraview module which is of version 5.10.1 . I have also created a dummy.foam file in \run\cavity and opening it using the paraview app installed of version 5.12.0-RC2. It still shows same result. Please help me in resolving the issue.